# Android Physics-Based Smooth Velocity Change Animation example code

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-animation

I am trying to implement a physics-based translation animation similar to the shown in the Android docs. I need a smooth change in velocity exactly same as in the example below. I searched online docs and tutorials but no way to find the shown example. Could you give sample android java or kotlin code to generate this smooth velocity change animation? I have tried [`FlingAnimation`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/fling-animation.html) and [`SpringAnimation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/animation/SpringAnimation.html).

[image: Physics-based animation example]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, what did you try? If not, please try to do it yourself before asking for help.

Comment: I tried looking deeply into FlingAnimation and SpringAnimation in the official android docs. It did not help. There are various examples elsewhere with google search but everyone tries to do it on its own way not using these animation sets. There should have been a best practice way.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/sagar-viradiya/AndroidPhysicsAnimation) repo.

Comment: Do you have source code for the project above?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is time interpolation (or easing interpolation). You can create animations with different interpolators that can replicate real motion, for example a bouncing ball.

The animation you provided most likely is using a [DecelerateInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/DecelerateInterpolator.html).

There're many interpolators and you can also create your own. There are plenty tutorials on how to implement them.

See example: 
[Some xml based animations](https://www.journaldev.com/9481/android-animation-example)
[Bounce animation example (programatically)](https://sproutsocial.com/insights/bounce-animation-for-android/)

Comment: I am looking for Physics-Based Animation based solution. (combination of Fling and Spring Animations)

Comment: you need to write the necessary physics yourself, it shouldn't be hard to write a vectoral deceleration algorithm. you don't need a physics engine or so

Comment: No there has to be a way with SpringAnimation and FlingAnimations.